# Input certificate content into a bash script, then parse that input into an already existing file

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I'm currently working on a bash script to automatically generate a CSR, confirm existing certificate names (to prevent having to reconfigure the application) input the newly generated certificate from an internal Windows CA into an already existing .cer file previously created by the script, which then moves it into the relevant directories and stops/starts the application. I've got everything working so far apart from the input of the cert file contents into the script. I'm hoping the end user can have a prompt to paste the cert content into the console while the bash script is running. This will then need to insert the certificate content into an already created .cer file which is specified as a variable in the script (the certificate file contains the hostname and domain of the server).

I've tried using "read" as well as well as a "heredoc". Here are some examples of what I've tried:

```
echo Please paste the new certificate contents here

    read -rp input1 -d $'\04' << EOF
    
EOF
```

After trying various combinations I've been able to get the script to accept the multiline certificate file content, but it would then not insert the content into an already existing file.

I've also tried:

```
read -rp input -d $'\04' | cat << $filename > EOF
EOF
```

And this:

```
cat <<EOF > blank.cer

echo Paste here

EOF
```

But no luck either. Using heredoc seemed to sort the issue of the certificate file having multiple lines, but it's getting that input in the heredoc into the predetermined file. Thank you for your help.

Comment: (Learn to use the `{}` tool from the edit menu on selected text to format as data/code/error msgs (-; .) Please edit your question to clarify i you mean `append`(to the end) or `insert` (some place NOT at the end). I think you're very close to solving your problem. Good luck.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/377943/how-do-i-read-multiple-lines-from-stdin-into-a-variable might help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I fully understand what you're trying to do, but it sounds like you're making it much more complicated than it needs to be. Would something like this work?

```
echo "Please paste the new certificate contents here:"
cat >pastedcert.cer
```

`cat` simply copies what it gets as input to its output until it receives an end-of-file (Control-D from a terminal). Replace `pastedcert.cer` with whatever file you want the cert stored in. If you want to replace the contents of the "already existing .cer file", just use that filename. If you want to merge it or append it or something, you'll need to clarify that.

You could also store the pasted cert in a shell variable like this:

```
echo "Please paste the new certificate contents here:"
pastedcert=$(cat)
```